# how can i combine href with id number

Tags: database, joomla

Trying to get some data from db but I can't use href with id number in code.

I tried everything but coldn't make it.

```
 <?php 
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select(array($db->quoteName('title')));
    $query->select(array($db->quoteName('id')));
    $query->select(array($db->quoteName('start_date')));
    $query->select(array($db->quoteName('end_date')));
    $query->from($db->quoteName('#__rbid_auctions'));
    $db->setQuery($query);

    $results = $db->loadObjectList();

    // display the results
    foreach ( $results as $result) {
       echo <<<HTML
    <a href="index.php?option=com_rbids&task=viewbids&id={<?php echo $id; ?>}">$result->title . </a>
    HTML;
       echo "<p>" . $result->start_date . "</p>";
       echo "<p>" . $result->end_date . "</p>";
    }

    ?>
```

I will be appreciated if someone help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [joomla.se]  (hey cool, typing `[joomla.se]` made that link!)

Comment: The tabbing of your HEREDOC body and closing are incorrect.  In php7.3, you can use indentation to pretty up your code, but they must be tabbed at least as much as the opening.  Otherwise, don't tab them at all. Have a look: https://3v4l.org/YbtAo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demonstration of issue then my suggested solution: ([Online Demo](https://3v4l.org/s1YZG))

```
$result = new stdClass();
$result->id = 333;
$result->title = 'title text';

echo <<<HTML
<a href="index.php?option=com_rbids&task=viewbids&id={<?php echo $id; ?>}">$result->title . </a>
HTML;
```

Output:

> Notice: Undefined variable: id in /in/s1YZG on line 7
>
> ```
> <a href="index.php?option=com_rbids&task=viewbids&id={<?php echo ; ?>}">title text . </a>
> ```

- Notice that $id isn't a declared variable. If it was, it would be rendered but all characters between the curly braces are treated literally because you are trying to echo within an echo.

Without heredoc syntax (heredoc can be funny about tabbing depending on php version):

```
echo "<a href=\"index.php?option=com_rbids&task=viewbids&id={$result->id}\">{$result->title} . </a>";  // curly braces may help IDEs with highlighting
```

New Output:

> ```
> <a href="index.php?option=com_rbids&task=viewbids&id=333">title text . </a>
> ```

---

As for your query building syntax...

- You can save some typing and chain the method calls onto `getQuery()`.
- None of the `quoteName()` calls are necessary for stability/security, but if you insist on toeing Joomla's preferred practices, you can call `quoteName()` on the array in `select()`.

Suggested Code:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select($db->quoteName(array('title', 'id', 'start_date', 'end_date')))
            ->from($db->quoteName('#__rbid_auctions'));
$db->setQuery($query);

if (!$results = $db->loadObjectList()) {
    echo "No results";
} else {
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        echo "<a href=\"index.php?option=com_rbids&task=viewbids&id={$row->id}\">{$row->title} . </a>";       
        echo "<p>{$row->start_date}</p>";
        echo "<p>{$row->end_date}</p>";
    }
}
```

Here is another post where `loadObjectList()` is called after a SELECT query which includes query error checking: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22963/12352

When you have Joomla questions, please post them on Joomla Stack Exchange.

Comment: thank you for your warnings and suggestion.
your sugested code gives this error "syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting end of file " and current PHP version is 7.2.
I just took this part and works like a charm for me.
   echo "<a href=\"index.php?option=com_rbids&task=viewbids&id={$result->id}\">{$result->title} . </a>";

thank you again.
regards

Comment: Whoops I had a lingering `;` after `(true)` that was interrupting the method chaining.   Fixed now.

Comment: what if i want to get last 4 from id column. 
I tried this but didn't work
`$query->select(array($db->quoteName('id' DESC LIMIT '4')));`/

Comment: For ORDER chain with: `->order($db->quoteName('id') . " DESC")`. For LIMIT chain with `->setLimit(4)`.  In other words, remove the semicolon after the `from()` method call, then add the above two lines, then add the semicolon to the end of the `setLimit()` call.

Comment: I've got loads of fully explained Joomla query posts here: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12352+%5Bmysql%5D

Answer (score 0):

I would try it like this:

also you are trying to echo $id which isnt assigned. should be $results->id

```
 <?php 
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select(array('title', 'id', 'start_date', 'end_date' ));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__rbid_auctions'));
$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadObjectList();

// display the results
foreach ( $results as $key => $result) {
   echo ' <a href="index.php?option=com_rbids&task=viewbids&id='.$result->id .'>'.$result->title .'</a>';
   echo "<p>" . $result->start_date . "</p>";
   echo "<p>" . $result->end_date . "</p>";
}

?>
```

Comment: $query->select(array('title', 'id', 'start_date', 'end_date' ));

Comment: Hi Brett. Thank you for help. Some how your code makes this url **index.php/component/rbids/?task=viewbids&id=1%3Etender1%3C/a%3E%3Cp%3E2019-01-08%2000:00:00%3C/p%3E%3Cp%3E2019-01-31%2000:00:00%3C/p%3E%20%3Ca%20href=** and it doesn't work. maybe i am missing smth.

Comment: ahh.. sorry for the loop it should probably be done like this:

foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
 echo ' <a href="index.php?option=com_rbids&task=viewbids&id='.$result->id .'>'.$result->title .'</a>';
 echo "<p>" . $result->start_date . "</p>";
 echo "<p>" . $result->end_date . "</p>";
}